# Could not deallocate container for task attemptId NNN

Tags: hadoop, memory, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to understand how the container allocates memory in YARN and their performance based on different hardware configuration.

So, the machine has 30 GB RAM and I picked 24 GB for YARN and leave 6 GB for the system.

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=24576
```

Then I followed http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html to come up with some vales for Map & Reduce tasks memory.

I leave these two to their default value:

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
mapreduce.map.java.opts
```

But I change these two configuration:

```
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=20480
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=Xmx16384m
```

But when I place a job with that setting, I'm getting error and the job is killed by force:

```
2015-03-10 17:18:18,019 ERROR [Thread-51] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Could not deallocate container for task attemptId attempt_1426006703004_0004_r_000000_0
```

The only value which worked for me so far is setting reducer memory <= 12 GB, but why is that? Why I cannot allocate more memory or up to (2 * RAM-per-container?

So what I'm missing here? Is there any thing I need to consider as well while setting up those values for better performance?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a "-" in your java opts. Probably not the root cause of your problem, most likely a typo in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Missed that '-' during copy paste from another env. Thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved this issue by changing **yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb** value. In YARN, jobs must not use more memory than the server-side config yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb. Though I set the value for yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb but it should also reflect the maximum allocation size. So after updating maximum allocation, job worked as expected:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=24576
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=24576
```

Comment: I figured that's what it was... hadn't gotten around to writing the answer yet :P

Comment: You could have saved my 1 hr :@ :) I thought I changed that property but later I found out that I kept that value pretty lower than my total resource memory value.