# run hadoop wordcount example failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

**update**: I solved this problem, I find a warn says like`can't connect from cp26/127.0.1.1 to cp26:some_port`, I delete 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts.

I install hadoop-2.7.3 on three machine, all ubuntu14.04, one namenode and two datanode, each machine has 48GB RAM. after I run

```
hadoop jar hadoop-install/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar wordcount input output
```

I get these errors in shell

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1475857350322_0003_m_000062_2, Status : FAILED
```

I get these warn and error in logs

```
WARN [CommitterEvent Processor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Could not delete hdfs://master:54310/user/hadoop/output/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1475857350322_0002_m_000020_0
ERROR [Thread-52] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Could not deallocate container for task attemptId attempt_1475857350322_0002_r_000000_0
ERROR [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Container complete event for unknown container id container_1475857350322_0002_01_000170
```

my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.task.timeout</name>
    <value>1800000</value> <!-- 30 minutes -->
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx1639m</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx3277m</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>master:54311</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>master:10020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>master:19888</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

my yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>43008</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>43008</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx3277m</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>2.1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>master</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>master:8030</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>master:8032</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>master:8088</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>master:8031</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>master:8033</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970528/could-not-deallocate-container-for-task-attemptid-nnn

Comment: I've set `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you set the yarn configuration based on the below link `https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.3/bk_installing_manually_book/content/determine-hdp-memory-config.html#ref-cb07873e-edba-4c77-bd34-edbcefcbfc16` ?

Comment: Yes, I follow this guide.

Comment: can you share the  yarn-env.sh

Comment: https://gist.github.com/suiyuan2009/edc683ed9e97c34733518d15e4dd72c1, I did not modify this file.

Comment: add `export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client
export YARN_LOG_DIR=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/$USER
export YARN_PID_DIR=/var/run/hadoop-yarn/$USER
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/libexec
export JAVA_HOME=JAVAPATH'  in top of yarn-env.sh, restart daemons and try again.

Comment: didn't work, do you know `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Could not delete hdfs://master:54310/user/hadoop/output/_temporary/1/_temporary/` mean?

Answer (score 0):

hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar pi  5 10

```
nano inputdata # write anything in it for processing.

hadoop fs -put inputdata .

hadoop fs -ls -R

df -h inputdata

hadoop fs -df -h inputdata

hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar wordcount inputdata outputresults

hadoop fs -ls

hadoop fs -mkdir yourname

hadoop fs -ls
```

Comment: I run the pi example, but if I set two numbers large, then it will fail, same warns and errors, in shell I finally got `16/10/08 01:49:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 87% reduce 29%
16/10/08 01:49:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/10/08 01:49:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1475862047615_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1475862047615_0004_m_000017
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
` and `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://master:54310/user/hadoop/QuasiMonteCarlo_1475862520954_686175580/out/reduce-out`.

Comment: If I set two numbers small in pi example, it will success.

Comment: there might be problem with heap size